# Run a background process and then kill it after some intermediate processing

Tags: python, background-process, fabric

Specifically, I'm trying to use fabric to run some tests which rely on the existence of a MongoDB.

I have the following code:

```
db_cmd = 'mongod'
test_cmd = 'istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec'
pid = os.spawnl(os.P_NOWAIT, db_cmd)
with shell_env(NODE_ENV='test'):
    local(test_cmd)
```

I plan to use the PID to kill the process after the `test_cmd` has finished however I've not gotten that far yet.

The running of `test_cmd` results in an error suggesting that `db_cmd` has exited and that MongoDB is no longer available:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
```

However running `mongod` manually before running fabric causes `test_cmd` to run fine and interact with MongoDB.

I suspect I'm just not understanding `os.spawnl`. Note that this code needs to run on Windows / Linux and OSX so I think I'm somewhat restricted in which `os.spawnxxx` methods I can use. I'm also interested to know if there's a fabric method to achieve this as well though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully use:

```
os.killpg(process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

Probably, you need to use subprocess module for that.

To run mongo in background use:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
        command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid
    )
```

To kill it after tests, use command I 've written first.

command - is a string contained your mongo start code, for example :

```
mongod --host localhost --port 27018
```

It works fine for me. If you will have problems wit the code, please let me know it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in straight bash with jobs and traps:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 trap "kill %1" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

 mongod --host localhost --port 27018 &
 istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec     

 exit 0
```

What this is doing:

- Set a trap on signals, SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT, to kill the first backgrond job
- Make a mongod instance, and throw it into the background (the first one)
- Run the tests
- trigger exit signal

So this will setup and tare down your mongod instance on completion, even on a term signal or exception.